# Which prime numbers in $\mathbb Z$ are precisely the prime elements of $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Which prime numbers in $\mathbb Z$ are precisely the prime elements of $\mathbb Z[i]$ and why?

In my book it has been left as an exercise to show that a prime number in $\mathbb Z$ is a prime element of $\mathbb Z[i]$ if and only if it is of the form $4k + 3$.

How can I proceed?Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?  What have you tried?  Try looking at an example prime of $\Bbb Z$ that fails to be prime in $\Bbb Z[i]$, can you see how it should be factored?

Comment: See answer $(1)$ of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458795/whats-are-all-the-prime-elements-in-gaussian-integers-mathbbzi

Comment: One solution is presented [here](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/nti/chap6.pdf)

Comment: The prime elements which are of the form $4k + 1$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares due to Fermat's theorem.Though I don't understand the proof clearly.In fact I have understood two proposition of Euler from wikipedia.But I have stuck when I tried to understand the lemma which asserts that "If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime to each other then each factor of $a^2 + b^2$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares." Can you please help me understanding it from wikipedia?Then it will really help me a lot.