# A question about prime decomposition

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If a prime number $p$ that isn't a Gaussian prime number,and can be decomposed into the sum of a square number $m^2$ and a prime number $q$,whether the prime number $q$ isn't a Gaussian prime number？For example,$p=113$,$m=4$,$q=97$;$p=113$,$m=10$,$q=13$.

Comment: What's your question, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those unfamiliar with the term, a "Gaussian prime" is a prime in the ring of Gaussian integers, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.  Since $2$ or any prime congruent to $1\pmod 4$ factors in the Gaussian integers, the only primes in $\mathbb{Z}$ which are Gaussian primes are those which are congruent to $3 \pmod 4$.  (See, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222907/primes-in-gaussian-integers).)

So the question becomes this:  If $p \not\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ is a prime and $p = m^2 + q$ with $q$ prime, then is $q \not\equiv 3 \pmod 4$?

The answer is yes.  If $p = 2$, the only possibility is $m=0$, $q=2$.  Otherwise, $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  We cannot have $m$ odd, as that would imply $m^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so $q$ would be a multiple of $4$.  If $m$ is even, then $m^2\equiv 0\pmod 4$, so $q\equiv 1\pmod 4$.